# NestJS Typeorm issue saving many-to-many with custom fields

Tags: typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have an issue updating a many-to-many relationship with custom fields.

`Program`:

```
@Entity()
export class Program {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;
  
  @OneToMany(() => CountryProgram, (countryProgram) => countryProgram.program, {eager: true})
  countryProgram: CountryProgram[];
}
```

`Country`:

```
@Entity()
export class Country {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  currency: string;

  @OneToMany(() => CountryProgram, (countryProgram) => countryProgram.country, {eager: true})
  countryProgram: CountryProgram[];
  
}
```

And `CountryProgram`:

```
@Entity()
export class CountryProgram {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  id: string;
  
  @ManyToOne(() => Country, (country) => country.countryProgram)
  public country: Country;

  @ManyToOne(() => Program, (program) => program.countryProgram, {cascade: true})
  public program: Program;

  @Column('decimal', { precision: 10, scale: 2 })
  price: number;
}
```

Saving an initial program, without any relations, works as expected. However, when I want to update the program I get the following error: `Cannot query across one-to-many for property countryProgram`.

I use the repository-pattern that Nest provides as such:

```
update(id: number, updateProgramDto: UpdateProgramDto) {
    return this.programsRepository.update(id, updateProgramDto);
  }
```

The DTO looks as followed:

```
export class CreateProgramDto {
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  name: string;
}

export class UpdateProgramDto extends PartialType(CreateProgramDto) {
    countryProgram: CountryProgram[]
}
```

The `CountryProgram`  refers to the CountryProgram entity as stated above. I am using typeorm `0.3.17` with postgres. I'm really wondering what causes `Cannot query across one-to-many for property countryProgram` to be thrown. Any help is appreciated :)